# script php to update stock

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, stock

I'm using Magento 2.1.2
Since I'm not so good with php language, I would like to know if exists any way to update quantities in my catalog reading a file with 2 columns

```
    SKU      |  Qty
 889588...       3
```

and do a query like this

```
UPDATE table_stock SET qty = x WHERE sku = y
```

If the qty is 0 the product has to be out of stock.

My Idea is to create a php file and update it on the root of magento installation on the server, and run it calling it's path.

Comment: you can export csv from backend.

Comment: @Rakesh I would like to import quantities

Comment: yes you can import csv using backend, you dont need to do update script.

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: @Rakesh yes, this is a good idea but it seems to be not too fast...I have to do this every evening and maybe more times a day... I'm searching for something faster if it's possible...

Answer (score 4):

I've written the following script to achieve what you asked for. I suggest placing this outside your root Magento directory inside a scripts folder so this is not accessible by browser.

Create file in suggested directory: `/var/www/html/magento/scripts/update-low-qty.php`. Add the following:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('../htdocs/app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

//list of products to check

//sku => update quantity
$products = [
    'test-product-1' => 3,
    'test-product-2' => 6,
    'test-product-3' => 30
];

echo "Starting...\n";


$_zeroQtyProducts = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('sku', array_keys($products));
$_stockState = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$_stockRegistry = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

//if any products found
if($_zeroQtyProducts) {
    echo sprintf("Found %s product(s) with a qty of 0\n", count($_zeroQtyProducts));

    foreach ($_zeroQtyProducts as $_product) {
        $_stock = $_stockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $_sku = $_product->getSku();

        echo sprintf("## Processing %s ##\n", $_sku);

        //do a double check quantity is 0 and product has been set to update
        if ((int)$_stock == 0 && isset($products[$_sku])) {
            $_stockItem = $_stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId());
            $_stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',1); //set updated data as your requirement
            $_stockItem->setData('qty', $products[$_sku]); //set updated quantity
            $_stockItem->save(); //save stock of item
            $_product->save();
            echo sprintf("Product had 0 qty..updated to: %s\n", $products[$_sku]);
        }

        echo sprintf("## Finished processing %s ##\n", $_sku);
    }

} else {
    echo sprintf("0 Products found with provided SKU's.\n");
}


exit("Finished.");
```

Then run this script by command line by running `php update-low-qty.php`.

To configure which product sku's get updated and what they get updated to, add to the products array which is in the format of `product_sku => quantity_to`.

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer, in the next days I will try this solutions and I let you know. In case I will set you as answer.

Comment: Was this answer useful @MartinaF ?

Comment: it's workig fine But how can i update both price and qty @ same time ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First export your product from backend : `System / Export /
   Products` as CSV.
2. Update the qty column of the CSV file with Excel or similar
   application.
3. Then import the CSV from backend : `System / Import / Products` with
   `Add / Update` as the import behavior

Comment: yes, this is a good idea but it seems to be not too fast...I have to do this every evening and maybe more times a day... I'm searching for something faster if it's possible...

Comment: You can create a script to generate your CSV file with the correct qty. You do not need to fill all colums. Then you can manually import them. If you have Magento 2 EE, you can schedule the product import.

Comment: You can check with the community extensions. Such as http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/magento-stock-inventory-import-module.html . I never used it.